# Can not refresh Tableview with data from database (mysql)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to refresh my tableView with data from mysql database but even though I can fetch the data, the tableview is not updating.

This is my controller class for my application

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package usermanagementsoftwere;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
*
* @author JOSE FOUNDATION
*/
public class UsersController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TableView<User> tableUsers;
@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> colId;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> colName;

@FXML
private TableColumn<User, String> colEmail;

@FXML
private Button Register;

private ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private DBConnect connect;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


  try {
        connect = new DBConnect();
        users = connect.getUsersData();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
                "Cannot connect to the database");
    } 



    tableUsers.setItems(users);


    colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("id"));
    colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("name"));
    colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("email"));



}



@FXML
void registerButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    openRegistrationForm();
}



private void openRegistrationForm(){
     try {
         FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
         fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("registration_form.fxml"));
         Stage stage = new Stage();
         stage.setTitle("Registration Form FXML Application");
         stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 500));
         stage.show();
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(UsersController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}

public void refreshTable(){
      try {
        connect = new DBConnect();
        users = connect.getUsersData();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
                "Cannot connect to the database");
    } 



}

}
```

Getting the data is no problem, but it refreshing the tableView that is the issue.

Here is the controller for the application that is supposed to trigger the tableView refresh. I'm trying to trigger the tableView refresh in the submitData() method (when I submit the user form):

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package usermanagementsoftwere;

/**
*
* @author JOSE FOUNDATION
*/
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class RegistrationFormController implements Initializable{
@FXML
private TextField nameField;

@FXML
private TextField emailField;

@FXML
private PasswordField passwordField;

@FXML
private Button submitButton;


UsersController users;

DBConnect connect = null;

 @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("usersgui.fxml"));
    try {
        Parent root = loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrationFormController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        this.users = (UsersController) loader.getController();

}

@FXML
protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Window owner = submitButton.getScene().getWindow();
    if(nameField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, owner, "Form Error!",
                "Please enter your name");
        return;
    }
    if(emailField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, owner, "Form Error!",
                "Please enter your email id");
        return;
    }
    if(passwordField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, owner, "Form Error!",
                "Please enter a password");
        return;
    }


    submitData();




}

public void submitData(){

    try {
        connect = new DBConnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
                "Cannot add user to the database");
    } 


    try {
        connect.submitData(nameField.getText(), emailField.getText(),
                passwordField.getText());

        //here is where I trigger the refresh
        users.refreshTable();

        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,null, "Registration Successful!",
           "Successfully Registered "  + nameField.getText());



        Stage stage = (Stage) submitButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
                "Cannot add user to the database");
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrationFormController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the database class just in case, although like I said it works just fine:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package usermanagementsoftwere;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

/**
*
* @author JOSE FOUNDATION
*/
public class DBConnect {
private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public DBConnect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserManagementSystem","root","");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserManagementSystem?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
        st = con.createStatement();



}

public ObservableList<User> getUsersData() throws SQLException{
    ObservableList<User> users = FXCollections.observableArrayList();;

        String query = "select * from users";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){

            User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id")),
                    rs.getString("name"),rs.getString("email"));

            users.add( user);
        }



    return users;
}

public void submitData(String name, String email, String password) throws SQLException{
   // String query = "insert into users (name, email, password)"
         //   +" values("+name+","+email+","+password")";



        String query = "insert into users (name, email, password)"
            +" values(?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, name);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, email);
        preparedStmt.setString(3, password);

        preparedStmt.execute();




}
}
```

Your help would be really appreciated. I've tried to solve it on my own but I'm not getting any headway.

Comment: Possibly unrelated: why are you importing `java.awt.event.ActionListener` in a JavaFX application?

Comment: sorry haha, I didnt clean up the imports before I uploaded the question

Comment: When I get data from the database, I add it to a `List` instead of an `ObservableList`. That way, once I create my `ObservableList` in the `Controller`, I only have to do `observableList.addAll(dbconnect.getUsersData());`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `users = connect.getUsersData();` in your `refreshTable()` method, you are replacing the `users` list with a new list. So now the `TableView` is referring to a different list than the one you're updating.

Instead, reuse the same `users` list and just update its items:

```
public void refreshTable(){
    try {
        connect = new DBConnect();
        users.setAll(connect.getUsersData());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
                "Cannot connect to the database");
}
```

Comment: this solution did not work. I'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `ObservableList` to `List`.

```
public List<User> getUsersData() throws SQLException{
    List<User> users = new ArrayList();

        String query = "select * from users";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){

            User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id")),
                    rs.getString("name"),rs.getString("email"));

            users.add( user);
        }



    return users;
}
```

Then in initialize:

```
tableUsers.setItems(users);
try {
        connect = new DBConnect();
        users.addAll(connect.getUsersData());
} catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
                "Cannot connect to the database");
}
```

Then:

```
public void refreshTable(){
    try {
        connect = new DBConnect();
        users.addAll(connect.getUsersData());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, null, "Error!",
       "Cannot connect to the database");
    } 
}
```

Also if you are going to call `connect = new DBConnect();` in many places within the `Controller`, I personally think you should close the connection after getting the info you need. When I program, I take one of two approaches. I either keep the database open until the program ends and then close the database; or I open the database each time, get the info I need, and then close the database right away.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it still isnt working

Comment: I am guessing you have a problem somewhere else. How did you verify that it's not working?

Comment: It's updating in the database not it's not reflecting on the tableView